# Extract output from FindMaximum inside a function

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

I have a function similar to this

```
 f[a_] := FindMaximum[{3 x, x < 1}, x]
```

which outputs

```
 {3., {x -> 1.}}
```

how do I change it so that the output is just the value that maximizes f (i.e. no lists, no arrows, just the real number)

Comment: `x /. FindMaximum[{3 x, x < 1}, x][[2]]`

Comment: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505

Answer (score 4):

`FindMaximum` results in an output in the format of

> ```
> {fmax, {x -> xmax}}
> ```

If you only want the maximum value `fmax`, you can use [`FindMaxValue[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaxValue.html) and if you only want `xmax` then you can use [`FindArgMax[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindArgMax.html).
In your case, the output of `FindArgMax[]` is a list that contains only one number. There are several ways to extract it. I used `First`:

```
First@FindArgMax[{3 x, x < 1}, x]
```

But why do you have it as a function of `a`? You don't have `a` in your function definition.

Comment: This is probably the best solution for somebody who gets tripped up on extracting stuff from lists. For completeness, I would suggest that you discuss `FindMaxValue[]` as well.

Comment: @J.M. Good idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[a_] := FindMaximum[{3 x, x < 1}, x][[2, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: honestly, slicing lists in mathematica is totally unintuitive

Comment: @andy, well, it's unintuitive if you don't have sufficient practice, sure.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is more intuitive if we use rules:

```
FindMaximum[{3 x, x < 1}, x] /. {result_, {x -> _}} -> result
```